# Injecting Mockito mocks into beans returned through factory methods

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I have the following set up:

A sample class that needs to be mocked during testing:

```
@Component
class MyConfig
{
    public String getConfig()
    {
        return "RealValue";
    }
}
```

An interface that defines a single method and has two implementations:

```
interface MyInterface
{
    String myMethod();
}

class MyImpl1 implements MyInterface
{
    private final MyInterface delegate;
    private final MyConfig config;

    public MyImpl1(final MyInterface delegate, final MyConfig config)
    {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.config = config;
    }

    @Override
    public String myMethod()
    {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + config.getConfig() + ", " + delegate.myMethod() + ";";
    }
}

class MyImpl2 implements MyInterface
{
    private final MyConfig config;

    public MyImpl2(final MyConfig config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }

    @Override
    public String myMethod()
    {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + config.getConfig();
    }
}
```

A factory class that prepares a bean of type `MyInterface` using the `MyConfig` object that is a spring bean injected into `MyFactory`:

```
@Component
class MyFactory
{
    @Autowired
    private MyConfig config;

    // Factory method to create the bean.
    @Bean(name = "myInterface")
    protected MyInterface myInterface()
    {
        final MyImpl2 myImpl2 = new MyImpl2(config);
        final MyImpl1 myImpl1 = new MyImpl1(myImpl2, config);
        return myImpl1;
    }

    // A simple getter that prepares MyInterface on the fly.
    // This is just to demonstrate that getter picks the mock where as 
    // the factory bean doesn't
    public MyInterface getInterface()
    {
        final MyImpl2 myImpl2 = new MyImpl2(config);
        final MyImpl1 myImpl1 = new MyImpl1(myImpl2, config);
        return myImpl1;
    }
}
```

A simple test case that checks if the mock version of `MyConfig` is getting into the bean created using `@Bean` or not:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath:application-context.xml"
})
public class SpringBeanMockExampleTest
{
    @Mock
    private MyConfig config;

    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    protected MyFactory factory;

    @Resource
    private MyInterface myInterface;

    @Before
    public void setupMocks()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    /**
     * Fails as the return value is "MyImpl1: RealValue, MyImpl2: RealValue;"
     */
    @Test
    public void testBean()
    {
        Mockito.when(config.getConfig()).thenReturn("MockValue");
        Assert.assertEquals("MyImpl1: MockValue, MyImpl2: MockValue;", myInterface.myMethod());
    }

    /**
     * Assertion passes here.    
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetter()
    {
        Mockito.when(config.getConfig()).thenReturn("MockValue");
        Assert.assertEquals("MyImpl1: MockValue, MyImpl2: MockValue;", factory.getInterface().myMethod());
    }
}
```

I expected the `testBean` method to pass also, but obviously the mock is not getting injected into the factory bean created in `MyFactory`.

It seems the mocks are replacing the actual beans after the factory bean creation step is completed. Due to this, the reference in factory beans is not updated with the mock.

How can I fix this so that `testBean` works as expected?

Comment: Can you please try it with add setConfig to MyFactory and set it with Mock object at SpringBeanMockExampleTest#setUpMocks as factory.setConfig(config)//your Mock object.

Comment: @erhun, that still didn't work. It seems the mocks are replacing the actual beans after the factory bean creation step. due to this the reference in factory beans is not updated with the mocks.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work.

Your Spring context is initialized first. Afterwards the `TestExecutionListener`s are executed that handle the dependency injection in your test (e.g. `@Autowired`).

Then, before each test is run, your `@Before` method will initialize the Mockito mocks in your test instance of `SpringBeanMockExampleTest`, effectively overriding the autowired Spring dependencies.

Why? Mockito creates a new instance for all attributes annotated with `@InjectMocks`, `@Mock`, `@Spy` and `@Captor`.

A possible solution would be to manually set the mocked config in the factory, instead of using `@InjectMocks`, overriding the Spring config bean.

```
@Before
public void setupMocks(){
    Config config = mock(Config.class);
    factory.setConfig(config);    
}
```

Please note that combining mocks with a (Spring) integration tests is **bad practice**, since mocking should only be done in unit tests.

A better setup would be to setup a separate `Config` bean in your Spring context using profiles, e.g.:

```
@Profile("testing")
@Component
public class TestConfig implements Config {
    public String getConfig(){
        return "testValue";    
    }
}
```